# center text in div

Tags: html, css

```
  <div>
<div class="left">
  <div align="center" class="node">
    <div class="nodeText">
      <h2 >test</h2>
      
  </div>
  <div class="node">
      <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
      <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
<div>
```

I need to center text in div nothing seems to work

```
.left {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
}
.node {
  height:200px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.nodeText{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h2{
     text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean vertical centering, horizontal centering or both?

Horizontal centering of **inline** content is easy. Just apply `text-align: center` to the containing block. Centering horizontally a block within another block with CSS is typically done with:

```
#centerMe { margin: 0 auto; }
```

**Note:** on IE6 this requires that IE be in "standards compliant" rather than "quirks" mode. To force this **always** put a [`DOCTYPE`](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) on your HTML document. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Vertical centering is much worse.

You may want to look at [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html). This is actually a non-trivial problem. The `vertical-align` style property you're using only applies to table cells (in a cross-browser backwards compatible way). This would be trivial to do with a table for what it's worth.

Comment: text-align for IE... other browsers can use: margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1):

The HTML you have written works in my browser (FF 3.5.8). However you are missing two closing `<\div>` tags. Maybe your browser is stricter than mine. Also, `<center>` is deprecated so try to avoid it where possible.

I would put all of this in comments but my rep ain't high enough yet! :/

Comment: using chrome and tried firefox centering   doesn't work  nether of them

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your `.nodeText` div.

Comment: This shows that one of the first things to do when facing weird CSS behaviour is validating the HTML. :)